# Why can't I retrive the data I want in the centain cell of the table?

Tags: python, pyqt, qabstracttablemodel, qmodelindex

Basiclly in the first function I have got the cell I have selected using the mouse, and I'm able to ret
rive the data from it by the data() method and display it in the first function.

However, I want to change it a bit into the way that when I choose a cell it will show the data from the first cell(first column) in that row. Since I already have the index(currentCell) of the selected cell I just instantiate a new ModelIndex object and assign the selected index to it. And then I change the object's column to 0. Finally , I want to retrive the data with the new object using data() mtohod, but nothing was there.It is null.I spend much time on it and don't know what is the problem. 
Thanks for anyone who've  offered some efforts to help and read :)

```
def tbRobotChanged(self, currentCell):          
 # get the selected cell's index from currentCell,Implement the Slot method

    self.statusBar().showMessage("Slected Robot is "+ 
    currentCell.data().toString())

def tbRobotChangedt(self,currentCell):

    crow_header_Index =  QtCore.QModelIndex()
    crow_header_Index = currentCell
    crow_header_Index.column = 0

    self.statusBar().showMessage("Slected Robot:"+crow_header_Index.data().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just construct or modify `QModelIndex` instances like that. It's the model's job to create and hand them. You should ask the model (`.index` method) the `QModelIndex` for the first column in that row:

```
def tbRobotChangedt(self,currentCell):

    model = currentCell.model()
    # or if you keep your model in a variable, use it.

    # .index normally takes 3 arguments.
    # row, column, parent
    # If this is a table model, you won't need the third argument.
    # because table is flat. no parents
    firstColumn = model.index(currentCell.row(), 0)

    # then get data as usual
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Selected Robot: %s" % firstColumn.data().toString())
```

Comment: Well, it works pretty well.This is my first post here.It's very nice of you to explain in such a detailed way.Thx for your help.

Comment: @Derek: I'm glad it helped. Welcome to SO :). Be sure to check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for better experience.